# Automate Wordpress Installation on Client Side

Tags: wordpress, wamp, bitnami, lampp, multisite

I want to allow users to create name path websites on my domain. I don't want them to have to use any sort of cPanel, rather just enter basic information in a form and have automation take care of the rest. Does anyone know if bitnami or softalicious or whatever has an API that can run behind the scenes to automatically create name path websites on our IP with unique subdomains/domains?

We can code from scratch but I'd certainly like to take advantage of any tools that exist if there are one's.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am no expert but is that not what WordPress Mu does.

Comment: Wordpress Multisite will allow you to create the sites and achieves most everything I need. However it requires manual setup by the admin. I just want to automate that task, and was hoping there was an existing solution for that. :\

Comment: Also I think you are referring to the older version of the project for Multisite (https://mu.wordpress.org/)